# Change order of multidimensional array columns

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, multiple-columns

I have a multidimensional array in php and i need to change the column order with the order of a second simple array.

EDIT:
Although both arrays are the same in regard of values and keys, im using this for export with phpexcel, and it generates the xls file with the order of the given array. I need to change that order so the xls file looks that way.

The array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Name1
            [sn] => Sn1
            [somenumber] => 43234234
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Name2
            [sn] => Sn2
            [somenumber] => 4564564
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Name3
            [sn] => Sn3
            [somenumber] => 6575647456745
        )
)
```

And the second array is this:

```
Array
        (
            [0] => sn
            [1] => name
            [2] => somenumber
        )
```

What i need is the first array to be ordered based on the second so it looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sn] => Name1
            [name] => Sn1
            [somenumber] => 43234234
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [sn] => Name2
            [name] => Sn2
            [somenumber] => 4564564
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [sn] => Name3
            [name] => Sn3
            [somenumber] => 6575647456745
        )
)
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something the first and last array in your question are the same. How they are displayed when using `print_r` doesn't really matter, or shouldn't, and since the indexes and values are the same so are the arrays.

Comment: Im using this array for export in an xls file with phpexcel. It generates the xls with the order of the keys, and i need a different order. The data, as you say, is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all keys always present

```
// Make template array with correct order of keys
$template = array_flip($second);

foreach($array as &$x) {
   // replace values in template
   $x = array_replace($template, $x);
}
```

[**demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/15089253c83918ebe9e11cf7893ba5e2d93429b3)

Comment: This is great, but $x only have the last item in the array.

Comment: I made this based on your answer:
for ($i=0; $i < count($info); $i++) { 
   $array[$i] = array_replace($template, $array[$i]);
}
It works, but maybe there is a better option since the arrays have 20k indexes.

Comment: It works with your code too - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/45291ecb4d9e3865c06e6a09f2a929bed1d610f2

Answer (score 2):

this is how you can sort your array:
$template array:

```
//template array
$reference = array('sn', 'name', 'somenumber');
$array_to_sort = Array
(
    "0" => Array
        (
            "somenumber" => "Name1",
            "sn" => "Sn1",
            "name" => "43234234"
        ),

    "1" => Array
        (
            "sn" => "Name2",
            "somenumber" => "4564564",
            "name" => "Sn2"
        ),

    "2" => Array
        (
            "sn" => "Name3",
            "name" => "Sn3",
            "somenumber" => "6575647456745"
        )
);
    $ordered_array = [];
    foreach ($array_to_sort as $key => $value) {
      $ordered_array[] = array_replace(array_flip($reference), $value);
    }

    print_r($ordered_array);
```

Comment: nice job, works even if not all keys are defined